# Conflict with Vertical tabs module when inserting a jwyswiyg editor

Tags: wysiwyg

We have created a custom module to control/insert the jwysiwyg editor onto text areas. We would use wysiwyg module, however, we had conflicts with regards to custom plugins.

Everything is working great, except there is a conflict with vertical tabs which causes jwysiwyg editor buttons to repeat themselves several times. I have verified that this is due to VT, as the duplications disappear once VT is disabled.

I suspect it has something to do with drupal behaviors or attachbehaviors being called multiple times. However stack trace in attachbehaviors and in my custom jywsiwyg code doesn't reveal multiple calls. I'm at a dead end.

Here is my jwysiwyg javascript insert code:

```
(function($) {

Drupal.jwysiwyg = Drupal.jwysiwyg || {};
Drupal.behaviors.jwysiwyg = function() {
  var default_settings = {
    iFrameClass: "jwysiwyg",
    initialContent: "",
    rmUnusedControls: true, 
    autoSave: true,
    controls: {
      fileManager: {
        visible: true,
        groupIndex: 12,
        tooltip: "Insert images",
        exec: function () {
          $.wysiwyg.fileManager.setAjaxHandler(Drupal.settings.jwysiwyg.url);
          $.wysiwyg.fileManager.init(this);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  $('.jwysiwyg:not(.jwysiwyg-processed)').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this).addClass('jwysiwyg-processed');
    var params = Drupal.jwysiwyg.getParams(this);

    if (($this.is(':input') && $this.is(':checked')) || $this.is('div')) {
      if (params.status == 1) {
      var settings = $.extend(true, default_settings, Drupal.settings.jwysiwyg[params.format]);
        $("#" + params.field).wysiwyg(settings);
      }
    }
    // Attach onChange handlers to input format selector elements.
    if ($this.is(':input')) {
      $this.change(function() {
        $("#" + params.field).wysiwyg('destroy');
        if (params.status == 1) {
          var settings = $.extend(true, default_settings, Drupal.settings.jwysiwyg[params.format]);
          $("#" + params.field).wysiwyg(settings);
        }
      });
      // IE triggers onChange after blur only.
      if ($.browser.msie) {
        $this.click(function () {
          this.blur();
        });
      }
    }
  });
};
```

clicking b/w input formats resolves the problem.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!